# BCP Export From Old SQL Server Version Turns Into Asian Character Set When BCP Imported/Written Into Newer SQL Server Version

Tags: sql-server, import, character-encoding, bcp

I have a script that unloads several tables from a very old SQL Server version 8.0.2039, and we are in the midst of getting off of that old version of Windows Server and SQL Server.

All but one of the unloaded tables import into SQL Server 11.0.7001 just fine. One of the tables turns into an Asian character set.

The export and import respectively use the BCP tools existing on their respective servers.

I am obviously not looking for an exact answer, but instead am looking for settings or parameters that might be affecting this. I am going to post the minimum number of lines from the export and import scripts.

Here is the bare, essential part of the export:

***%BcpPath% points directly to the directory containing bcp.exe***

***%UnloadPath% is the full path to the export directory, like D:\SQL_BKUPS***

***%ServitronName% is the name of the SQL server from which the export will occur.***

```
%BcpPath%bcp BuildingPermit..real_estate OUT %UnloadPath%\real_estate.unl
 -S %ServitronName% -U sa -P pwd -m 10000 -n
```

The .unl file is ftp'd over to the server that will import `real_estate.unl`.

Here is the bare, essential part of the import:

***%BcpPath% points directly to the directory containing bcp.exe***

***%ImportPath% is the full path to the import directory, like D:\sql_dbs. ***

***%ServitronName% is the name of the SQL server from which the export will occur.***

```
if not exist "%ImportPath%\real_estate.unl" goto noreal_estateUnl
    echo use BuildingPermit > d:\web\bin\tempPurgeRecs.sql
    echo go >> d:\web\bin\tempPurgeRecs.sql
    echo delete from real_estate >> d:\web\bin\tempPurgeRecs.sql
    echo go >> d:\web\bin\tempPurgeRecs.sql
    %BcpPath%sqlcmd -E %ServitronName% -U ispermits -P Permits99 -i d:\web\bin\tempPurgeRecs.sql 
    del d:\web\bin\tempPurgeRecs.sql
    %BcpPath%bcp BuildingPermit..real_estate in %ImportPath%\real_estate.unl -S %ServitronName% -U sa -P pwd -m 10000 -n
:noreal_estateUnl
```

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'm giving it a try.